# AngularJS show data if key exists

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a collection of data coming via `$http` call, in `JSON` format. It goes something like this:

```
{
"projects": [
        { "url": "http://project-1-url.com", "src": "images/projects/1.png", "title": "Project 1", "tags": ["AngularJS","Web Design","Self Project"]},
        { "src": "images/projects/2.png", "title": "Project 2","tags": ["HTML","Plugin","Self Project"]}
    ]
}
```

As you might've noticed, few objects in JSON doesn't have `URL` parameter. I am using `ngRepeat` to show the data something like this:

```
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="project in projects">{{ project.title }}</li>
</ul>
```

Where, the projects are coming from controller as:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function ( $scope, $http) {
   $scope.projects = null;
   $http.get("http://api-endpoint-here").then(function (response) {
            $scope.projects = response.data;
   });
});
```

I want to have some logic such that the JSON objects that have URL property should show up as links, while those not having one should just output title. Much like:

```
<!-- If JSON has URL -->
<li ng-repeat="project in projects"><a href="project.url">{{ project.title }}</a></li>
<!-- If JSON DO NOT have URL -->
<li ng-repeat="project in projects">{{ project.title }}</li>
```

Should I prepare some logic within controller? Or is it possible with some `ngShow` logic in the view?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not the prettiest, but works...

```
<li ng-repeat="project in projects">
    <span ng-if="project.url"><a href="project.url">{{ project.title }}</a></span>
    <span ng-if="!project.url">{{ project.title }}</span>
</li>
```

Comment: Do we need ng-if for every field? Is there an easiery way

Answer (score 1):

Its also possible to check hasOwnProperty like bellow

```
{{project.hasOwnProperty("url") ? project.url:""}}
```